# Cannot access wp-admin (wordpress dashboard)

Tags: php, wp-admin, dashboard

I am little bit new to WordPress. I have a WordPress site hosted in *BLUEHOST*. Today I  accidentally degraded my PHP version of it, Now I have *no access to WordPress dashboard*. Please help me If anyone knows why and know how to resolve this.

This is the error message

[image: this thing happen when I try to access my WordPress website's dashboard]

here is my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your ssl. if you try to access to website with http://french-american.tv/ you can see the website.
wp-admin force the ssl soo you have to fix this.
in bluehost go on advanced section > SSL. and fix in your domain.

**edit**

check this website for the [solution](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/err_ssl_unrecognized_name_alert/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it now

Comment: I have checked, SSL has already installed. Another thing is I have a subdomain called https://upload.french-american.tv and I can login to that's wordpress dashboard without any problem

Comment: try to go in Install and manage SSL for the site (HTTPS) and install or reinstall

Comment: if it's dosen't work check your .httacces

Comment: I have re-installed, but problem remains.

Comment: Also I tried to repair my database. Data base is ok

Comment: if you reinstall your wordpress installation, the problem is in ssl. Check in cpanel delete and reinstall the certificates

Comment: or (but it is highly discouraged) force the .htaccess not to use the ssl. However, this creates security problems. Hackers could use man in the middle

Comment: Thanks for the comments Edoardo. I called BLUEHOST and they said they have re installed SSL on my site. Thank you very much. Problem solved

Comment: you are welcome. check the tick